# Find all possible arrangements of a n numbers in an array

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers, permutation

I have an array which contains lets say [25,15,8,20] 
I want to find all possible arrangements of numbers that is possible.

expected output:

```
25 15 8 20
25 15 20 8
25 20 15 8
25 20 8 15
25 8 20 15
25 8 15 20
15 25 8 20
15 25 20 8
15 20 25 8
15 20 8 25
15 8 20 25
15 8 25 20
20 25 15 8
20 25 8 15
20 8 25 15
20 8 15 25
20 15 25 8
20 15 8 25
8 15 20 25
8 15 25 20
8 25 15 20
8 25 20 15
8 20 15 25
8 20 25 15


void print(int *num, int n)
{
 int i;
 for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    printf("%d ", num[i]);
   printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
 int num[N];
 int *ptr;
 int temp;
 int i, n, j;
 printf("\nHow many number you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
 printf("\nEnter a list of numbers to see all combinations:\n");
 for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
 for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        temp = num[i];
        num[i] = num[i+1];
        num[i+1] = temp;
        print(num, n);
 }
}
 return 0;
}
```

The above program is not giving all possible outputs. How do I get the internal swap and get the combinations

Comment: from the above code you will get 12 outputs only but there should be 24. but its not doing internal  swap.

Comment: your logic will only work for max 3 numbers. For 4 numbers, the total combination will be 4! i.e. 24. However, your loop is running only 4*3=12 times and thus printing only 12 combination. I don't see any issue with internal swaps.

Comment: for example, the first loop where 3 is fixed at the beginning, 4 stays far from second index, try to always fix any number, then permute the rest of couples using recursion.

Comment: Are all your numbers distinct? For example [1,2,2] will have just 3 combinations.

Answer (score 0):

- The trick is, you must not permute only adjacent values, see that when 3 is fixed at the index=1, 4 is never aside it, so you must extend permutations to further values gradually.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>  
  #include <string.h> 
  #include <malloc.h> 

  void print(int *num, int n) 
  {   
   int i; 
   for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) 
      printf("%d ", num[i]);  
     printf("\n");    
  }   

  int*permute(int*i,int h)    
  {       
       int temp = *i; 
      *i = *(i+h);    
      *(i+h) = temp;  
  return i+1; 

  }   
  void recursive_permute(int*i,int *j,int n)  
  {   
      if((j-i)==n-1) {print(i,n);return;};

      int *tmparray=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
      memcpy(tmparray,i,n*sizeof(int));
      recursive_permute(tmparray,tmparray+(j-i+1),n);

      for (int h=1;h<n-(j-i);h++) recursive_permute(tmparray,permute(tmparray+(j-i),h),n);
  }   

  int main()  
  {   
   int num[100];  
   int *ptr;  
   int temp;  
   int i, n, j;   
   printf("\nHow many number you want to enter: ");   
      scanf("%d", &n);    
   printf("\nEnter a list of numbers to see all combinations:\n");    
   for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++)   
      scanf("%d", &num[i]);   
   printf("my recursive method ---------------------------\n");   
   recursive_permute(num,num,n);  

   printf("your method -----------------------------------\n");   

   for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) { 
      for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) { 
          temp = num[i];  
          num[i] = num[i+1];  
          num[i+1] = temp;    
          print(num, n);  
   }  
  }   
   return 0;  
  }
  ```

### [See it running here](http://ideone.com/3a12Mz)

Answer (score 0):

There are several aspect to finding all permutations and the number of permutations. Shown with comments below, to calculate the number of permutations for `k` size groups in a total on `n` elements, you find the factorial on `n` divided by the factorial for number of `k` size groups that can make up `n` elements. For the case of finding all permutations for all 4 elements in a four elements array, there are `24` possible permutations.

The permutations available are then found recursively. Look over the following and let me know if you have any questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap (int *x, int *y);
unsigned long long nfact (size_t n);
unsigned long long pnk (size_t n, size_t k);
void permute (int *a, size_t i, size_t n);
void prnarray (int *a, size_t sz);

int main (void) {

    int array[] = { 25, 15, 8, 20 };
    size_t sz = sizeof array/sizeof *array;

    /* calculate the number of permutations */
    unsigned long long p = pnk (sz , sz);
    printf ("\n total permutations : %llu\n\n", p);

    /* permute the array of numbers */
    printf (" permutations:\n\n");
    permute (array, 0, sz);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap (int *x, int *y)
{   int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/* calculate n factorial */
unsigned long long nfact (size_t n)
{   if (n <= 0) return 1;
    unsigned long long s = n;

    while (--n) s *= n;

    return s;
}

/* calculate possible permutations */
unsigned long long pnk (size_t n, size_t k)
{   size_t d = (k < n ) ? n - k : 1;
    return nfact (n) / nfact (d);
}

/* permute integer array for elements 'i' through 'n' */
void permute (int *a, size_t i, size_t n)
{   size_t j;
    if (i == n)
        prnarray (a, n);
    else
        for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
            swap ((a+i), (a+j));
            permute (a, i+1, n);
            swap ((a+i), (a+j));  // backtrack
        }
}

void prnarray (int *a, size_t sz)
{   size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) printf (" %2d", a[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/permute4int

 total permutations : 24

 permutations:

 25 15  8 20
 25 15 20  8
 25  8 15 20
 25  8 20 15
 25 20  8 15
 25 20 15  8
 15 25  8 20
 15 25 20  8
 15  8 25 20
 15  8 20 25
 15 20  8 25
 15 20 25  8
  8 15 25 20
  8 15 20 25
  8 25 15 20
  8 25 20 15
  8 20 25 15
  8 20 15 25
 20 15  8 25
 20 15 25  8
 20  8 15 25
 20  8 25 15
 20 25  8 15
 20 25 15  8
```

**Note:** for strings, this approach works fine, but does *not* result in a lexical sorting of the possible permutations.