# How to print out all the permutation of a range of numbers in C using recursion?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I am trying to make a recursive function that would print out all the permutations with duplicates of an array of integers, but the numbers have a range, and the array size ranges as well. Say we have an array `num[2]` and it has a range from 0-1 for example, it would print out something like

```
00
01
11
10
```

If it were a simple permutation I could use a simple permutation function like this:

```
void permute(int *array,int i,int length) { 
  if (length == i){
     printArray(array,length);
     return;
  }
  int j = i;
  for (j = i; j < length; j++) { 
     swap(array+i,array+j);
     permute(array,i+1,length);
     swap(array+i,array+j);
  }
  return;
}

void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

but how do I make it go through a range of numbers of say n size with the given size of the array?

My question is different to another one here as I do not have a set array with what the values are, the example code does that but what I need is help with making print all the permutation of range n in an array of k spots, so say that n is 3  and k is 3 then it would be

```
000
001
002
003
010
011
etc...
```

Comment: Can you share swap function please?

Comment: void swap(int * x, int * y)
    {
        int temp;
        temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    }

Comment: I can't understand the "i" variable. What is that ?

Comment: And why do you need an array ? Input can be only a number. Say 2, result can be; 00 01 11 01 again. Am i right? And the other question, if you say 3, what will be the result?

Comment: actually yeah they could be, but incase I needed to store them or use them separately is why I have that, plus I figured its easier to find the permutations when they are separated in an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all possible arrangements of a n numbers in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920005/find-all-possible-arrangements-of-a-n-numbers-in-an-array)

Comment: Your example seems incorrect. I think you want to include `10` instead of having `01` appear twice.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you show sample input/output?

Comment: What is this "range" you keep talking about and how does it relate to your array?

Comment: input: k=2 n=3  output: 00 01 02 03 10 11 12 13 20 21 22 23 33 32 31 30

Comment: @F22lightning Why do you produce `n+1` outputs for `n` input? Also, what is `n`? And is there a range or an array involved?

Comment: @melpomene Based on the examples, I'd say `k` is the count of digits in each sequence, and `n` is the number of digits available in the range `0 .. n-1`. For example, if k=4 and n=2, 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 ... 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111. Alternatively, you could say `n` is the base that you count in, so n=2 is binary, n=3 is ternary, n=8 is octal, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have asked, you want for each array with `n` elements and the resulting array with `k` elements, print all n^k permutations. So in each position `i` we have to put each element of the array and continue doing this for the next one. Something like this code:

```
void permute(int *array, int *result, int i, int n, int length) {
    if (length == i){
        printArray(result, length);
        return;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        result[i] = array[j];
        permute(array, result, i + 1, n, length);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2 }, b[2];
    permute(a, b, 0, 3, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this seems to work for the most part except there is a problem, for some reason when attempted with 4 and 6 sometimes it works and other times it doesn't

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to generate the permutations of length `n` by concatenating each of the possible digits to each of the permutations of length `n-1`. So if you have digits 0-2 and you want to generate permutations of length 3, you first generate all the permutations of length 2, and then append or prepend the digits `0`, `1`, and `2` to each of those:

Permutations of length 2 are: 00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22

So permutations of length 3 are: 000, 001, 002, 010, 011, 012, 020, 021, 022, 100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112, 120, 121, 122, 200...

So, how do you generate all the permutations of length 2? You generate the permutations of length 1 and prepend each of your digits to all those permutations. How do you generate the permutations of length 1? There are no permutations of length 0, so you just list the digits.

Here's pseudocode:

```
permute(n, digits) {
    permutations = []
    smaller_permutations = permute(n-1, digits)
    for (i in digits) {
        if (length(smaller_permutation > 0) {
            for (j in smaller_permutations) {
                insert concatenate(i,j) into permutations
            }
        }
        else {
            insert i into permutations
        }
    }
    return permutations
}
```